# (Obj C) What if a smaller unsigned integer is divided by a larger unsigned integer?

Tags: objective-c, operators, arithmetic-expressions

I am new here and new to Objective C too.I tried out some sample while loop program, and there is something I simply do not understand.
I've set all the variables "v", "u" and "remainder" to be of unsigned integers.

```
unsigned int v, u, temp;    
NSLog(@"Please key in 2 non-negative integers");
scanf("%u %u", &u, &v);   
    while (v != 0) {
        temp = u % v;
        u = v;
        v = temp;
        NSLog(@"Value of v is %u, value of u is %u, value of temp is %u", v, u, temp);
    }       
 }
return 0;
}
```

The part that I do not understand is "temp = u % v".
I am aware that the "%" operator is used to find the remainder of the division of u by v, which is then assigned to variable "temp".

First I tried the values 150 and 35 which are stored in variables u and v respectively. When the program was executed, "temp" was assigned the value 10 (in the first loop), because 150/35 (u/v) leaves a remainder of 10.

I decided to switching the values; now I assigned u and v the values 35 and 150 respectively.
I expected "temp" to be 0 because 35/150 (u/v) would simply have no remainder for it is a fraction. But somehow, "temp" was assigned the value 35 (in the first loop) , and I just cannot find out why.

Why is "temp" assigned the value 35? I tried to Google "remainder of 35 divided by 150" to figure out why the % operator gave me 35 as a remainder but i couldn't find any answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%` does not perform division. For unsigned numbers, the remainder of dividing a smaller number by a larger number is always the smaller number itself.

Recall that

```
Dividend = Divisor * Quotient + Remainder
```

When `Divisor` is greater than `Dividend`, `Quotient` is zero. Hence

```
Dividend = Remainder
```

Comment: Quotient is 0 because both variables "v" and "u" are integers, therefore the operation is carried out under rules of integer arithmetic, which means the decimal place from the quotient "0.233333" is discarded, leaving the quotient as 0? Is this a correct statement?

Comment: @solomonbstoner Yes, this is correct. The `Remainder` makes sense only for integer division - once you allow real number division, the remainder is gone.